# Retrieve JSON array from Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a JSON array where I store a few items I want to display on my app's main menu. It looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to retrieve this list but for some reason I ignore the code below doesn't work:

```
DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mMainMenuRef = mRootRef.child("main_menu");

    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    mMainMenuRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String stringValue = ds.getValue(String.class);
                Log.i("Firebase", stringValue);
            }
        }

        ...

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference points to `/main_menu` in the database:

```
DatabaseReference mMainMenuRef = mRootRef.child("main_menu");
```

You then listen to that reference and loop over the data:

```
mMainMenuRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String stringValue = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.i("Firebase", stringValue);
        }
    }
```

This means that you loop over the child nodes directly under `/main_menu`, so `-L-FDnRW...`. You then try to get the string value of that node. But the `-L-FDnRW...` contains an entire JSON object, so there is no singular string value.

To get the value of a specific property under `-L-FDnRW...` use the `DataSnapshot.child()` method:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String stringValue = ds.child("0").getValue(String.class);
        Log.i("Firebase", stringValue);
    }
}
```

To show the value of all children, loop over the child snapshots:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      for (DataSnapshot prop : ds.getChildren()) {
        String stringValue = ptop.getValue(String.class);
        Log.i("Firebase", stringValue);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your modified code of yours, as per your requirement:

```
DatabaseReference mRootRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mMainMenuRef = mRootRef.child("main_menu");

@Override
protected void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

   mMainMenuRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

          for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {

                for (DataSnapshot property :dataSnapshot1.getChildren()) {
                    String value = property.getValue(String.class);
                    Log.i("Firebase", value);
                }
            }
       }

    ...

});
```